# Question MarkTags In WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have been trying to find answer to this question for a while now.

What is this tag for in WPF?

```
<?  ?>
```

Comment: Are you thinking about XML? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: It's part of the xaml intellisense in visual studio and complies in the xaml. What is it used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<? ?>` is an interface known as [`Processing Instruction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256173.aspx).

It's used in `XML` as a way to keep processor-specific information in the text of the document.

According to [Mozilla Developer Network(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/ProcessingInstruction)

> A processing instruction provides an opportunity for
>   application-specific instructions to be embedded within XML and which
>   can be ignored by XML processors which do not support processing their
>   instructions (outside of their having a place in the DOM).